# Exploded view of a string

Tags: code-golf, string

Don't you love those [exploded-view diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploded-view_drawing)  in which a machine or object is taken apart into its smallest pieces?

[image]

Let's do that to a string!

## The challenge

Write a program or function that

1. inputs a string containing only **printable ASCII characters**;
2. dissects the string into **groups of non-space equal characters** (the "pieces" of the string);
3. outputs those groups in any convenient format, with some **separator between groups**.

For example, given the string

```
Ah, abracadabra!
```

the output would be the following groups:

```
!
,
A
aaaaa
bb
c
d
h
rr
```

Each group in the output contains equal characters, with spaces removed. A newline has been used as separator between groups. More about allowed formats below.

## Rules

The **input** should be a string or an array of chars. It will only contain printable ASCII chars (the inclusive range from space to tilde). If your language does not support that, you can take the input in the form of numbers representing ASCII codes.

You can assume that the input contains **at least one non-space character**.

The **output** should consist of **characters** (even if the input is by means of ASCII codes). There has to be an unambiguous **separator between groups**, different than any non-space character that may appear in the input.

If the output is via function return, it may also be an array or strings, or an array of arrays of chars, or similar structure. In that case the structure provides the necessary separation.

A separator **between characters** of each group is **optional**. If there is one, the same rule applies: it can't be a non-space character that may appear in the input. Also, it can't be the same separator as used between groups.

Other than that, the format is flexible. Here are some examples:

- The groups may be strings separated by newlines, as shown above.
- The groups may be separated by any non-ASCII character, such as  `¬`. The output for the above input would be the string:

  ```
  !¬,¬A¬aaaaa¬bb¬c¬d¬h¬rr
  ```
- The groups may be separated by *n*>1 spaces (even if *n* is variable), with chars between each group separated by a single space:

  ```
  !  ,    A   a a a a a    b b  c       d   h  r r
  ```
- The output may also be an array or list of strings returned by a function:

  ```
  ['!', 'A', 'aaaaa', 'bb', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'rr']
  ```
- Or an array of char arrays:

  ```
  [['!'], ['A'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['h'], ['r', 'r']]
  ```

Examples of formats that are not allowed, according to the rules:

- A comma can't be used as separator (`!,,,A,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,c,d,h,r,r`), because the input may contain commas.
- It's not accepted to drop the separator between groups (`!,Aaaaaabbcdhrr`) or to use the same separator between groups and within groups (`! , A a a a a a b b c d h r r`).

The groups may appear in **any order** in the output. For example: alphabetical order (as in the examples above), order of first appearance in the string, ... The order need not be consistent or even deterministic.

Note that the input cannot contain newline characters, and `A` and `a` are different characters (grouping is **case-sentitive**).

Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

In each test case, first line is input, and the remaining lines are the output, with each group in a different line.

- Test case 1:

  ```
  Ah, abracadabra!
  !
  ,
  A
  aaaaa
  bb
  c
  d
  h
  rr
  ```
- Test case 2:

  ```
  \o/\o/\o/
  ///
  \\\
  ooo
  ```
- Test case 3:

  ```
  A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!
  !
  ,,
  :
  A
  P
  aaaaaaaaa
  c
  ll
  mm
  nnnn
  p
  ```
- Test case 4:

  ```
  "Show me how you do that trick, the one that makes me scream" she said
  ""
  ,
  S
  aaaaa
  cc
  dd
  eeeeeee
  hhhhhh
  ii
  kk
  mmmm
  n
  ooooo
  rr
  ssss
  tttttt
  u
  ww
  y
  ```

Comment: If we use non-ASCII symbols like "¬" as separator, can it be counted as 1 byte?

Comment: @LeakyNun No, it will be counted as it corresponds depending on the encoding used for the source code, as usual

Comment: Is a trailing newline after the last group acceptable?

Comment: Is a leading newline of output acceptable?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Sure. That can't be mistaken with any input char

Comment: Argh! Im too late to this party. A patch to SILOS was written at 12:00 AM this morning, It now can actually accept multiline string input. but it now would be noncepeting with this feature

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Can't you take input as an array of ASCII codes? I included that specially for you!

Comment: @LuisMendo ok I will.

Comment: Your third and fourth output format examples step from 5 'a's to 4 'a's.

Comment: @Delioth Thanks! Corrected

Comment: I think the proper term for this is "knolling": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoll_(verb)

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm almost there, One clarification can I output unpaced groups that have no members? Essentially my output is separated with n >= 1 new lines where n is variable

Comment: @LuisMendo I did it!

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Well done! :-) Yes, several newlines as separators is fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ḟ⁶ṢŒg
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bif4oG24bmixZJn&input=&args=J0EgbWFuLCBhIHBsYW4sIGEgY2FuYWw6IFBhbmFtYSEn)

It does return an array, just that when it is printed to STDOUT, the separator is gone.

This is indeed a function that can be called [as such](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bif4oG24bmixZJnCsOHxZLhuZg&input=&args=J0EgbWFuLCBhIHBsYW4sIGEgY2FuYWw6IFBhbmFtYSEn) (in Jelly, each line is a function).

```
ḟ⁶ṢŒg
ḟ⁶      filter out spaces
  Ṣ     sort
   Œg   group
```

Answer (score 24):

## Python 3.5+, <s>77</s> <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 41 bytes

```py
lambda s:[a*s.count(a)for a in{*s}-{' '}]
```

Pretty simple. Goes through the unique characters in the string by converting it to a set (using Python 3.5's extended iterable unpacking), then uses a list comprehension to construct the exploded diagrams by counting the number of times each character occurs in the string with `str.count`. We filter out spaces by removing them from the set.

The order of the output may vary from run to run; sets are unordered, so the order in which their items are processed, and thus this answer outputs, cannot be guaranteed.

This is a lambda expression; to use it, prefix `lambda` with `f=`.

<del>[Try it on Ideone!](http://ideone.com/axnIfH)</del> Ideone uses Python 3.4, which isn't sufficient.

Usage example:

```py
>>> f=lambda s:[a*s.count(a)for a in{*s}-{' '}]
>>> f('Ah, abracadabra!')
[',', 'A', 'aaaaa', 'd', '!', 'bb', 'h', 'c', 'rr']
```

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @shooqie!*

Comment: Congrats on 1k!

Comment: In Python >3.5 you can do `{*s}` for `set(s)`.

Answer (score 11):

## Retina, 13 bytes

```
O`.
!`(\S)\1*
```

The sorting is very easy (it's a builtin), it's separating the letters that takes 9 bytes. [Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=T2AuCiFgKFxTKVwxKg&input=QWgsIGFicmFjYWRhYnJhIQ)

The first line s`O`rts all matches of the regex `.` (which is every character), giving us  `!,Aaaaaabbcdhrr`.

Match is the default stage for the last line of a program, and `!` makes it print a linefeed-separated list of matches of the regex. The regex looks for one or more instances of a non-space character in a row.

Comment: What does the ! Do?

Comment: @Downgoat [It prints a linefeed-separated list of all matches of the regex, instead of the default count.](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#match)

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 28 bytes

```perl6
*.comb(/\S/).Bag.kv.map(*x*)
```

Note that [Bag](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Bag) like a [Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash) or [Set](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Set) is unordered so the order of results is not guaranteed.

### Explanation:

```perl6
# Whatever lambda ｢*｣


# grab the characters
*.comb(
  # that aren't white-space characters
  /\S/
)
# ("A","h",",","a","b","r","a","c","a","d","a","b","r","a","!")


# Turn into a Bag ( weighted Set )
.Bag
# {"!"=>1,","=>1,"A"=>1,"a"=>5,"b"=>2,"c"=>1,"d"=>1,"h"=>1,"r"=>2}


# turn into a list of characters and counts
.kv
# ("!",1,",",1,"A",1,"a",5,"b",2,"c",1,"d",1,"h",1,"r",2)


# map over them 2 at a time
.map(
  # string repeat the character by the count
  * x *
)
# ("!",",","A","aaaaa","bb","c","d","h","rr")
```

Answer (score 8):

## Vim, <s>50</s>, 46 bytes

```
i <esc>:s/./&\r/g
:sor
qq:%s/\v(.)\n\1/\1\1
@qq@qD
```

Explanation/gif will come later.

Comment: For once, Emacs & vim solutions look alike.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>14</s> 7 bytes

**7 bytes thanks to Fatalize.**

```
:@Sxo@b
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OkBTeG9AYg&input=IkEgbWFuLCBhIHBsYW4sIGEgY2FuYWw6IFBhbmFtYSEi&args=Wg)

```
:@Sxo@b
:@Sx     remove spaces
    o    sort
     @b  group
```

Comment: [7 bytes using `x` to remove `@S` (space).](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OkBTeG9AYg&input=IkEgbWFuLCBhIHBsYW4sIGEgY2FuYWw6IFBhbmFtYSEi&args=Wg) I believe this output format (list of strings) is valid

Answer (score 7):

### Pyth, 6

```
.gk-zd
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.gk-zd&input=Ah%2C%20abracadabra%21&debug=0) or run a [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.gk-zd&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Ah%2C+abracadabra%21%0A%5Co%2F%5Co%2F%5Co%2F%0AA+man%2C+a+plan%2C+a+canal%3A+Panama%21%0A%22Show+me+how+you+do+that+trick%2C+the+one+that+makes+me+scream%22+she+said&debug=0).

Pretty simple, `-zd` removes spaces from the input, and `.gk` groups each remaining element by its value. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to make use of auto-fill variables. Note that the output is shown as Python strings, so certain characters (read: backslashes) are escaped. If you want it to be more readable, add a `j` to the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 38 bytes

```haskell
f s=[filter(==c)s|c<-['!'..],elem c s]
```

Basically [nimi's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90993/20260), but explicitly checking only letters appearing in the string.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

```
s=>[...s].sort().join``.match(/(\S)\1*/g)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also cause an entry `"     "` to exist in the returned array, as well? Not sure if that's allowed

Comment: @ValueInk Bah, I thought about that when I started, but promptly forgot. Fixed now.

Comment: Umm, how is `join()` being called with those double backkticks ?

Comment: @TejasKale That's an ES6 template string. When you prefix a method to a template string, it passes the template as an array to the method, so in this case, it ends up calling `.join([''])`. `join` then converts that to the (empty) string and uses that to join the array elements. Not all methods convert their parameter to string, but this technique is handy on those that do.

Answer (score 5):

## [2sable](http://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 7 bytes

Code:

```
Úð-vyÃ,
```

Explanation:

```
Ú       # Uniquify the string, aabbcc would result into abc
 ð-     # Remove spaces
   vy   # For each character...
     Ã  #   Keep those in the string, e.g. 'aabbcc', 'a' would result into 'aa'
      , #   Pop and print with a newline
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=w5rDsC12ecODLA&input=QW5kIHRoZW4gRGVubmlzIHNhaWQ6ICJheXkgbG1hbywgbGV0IG1lIG91dGcwbGYgdSBpbiBqZWx5Ig)

Comment: That doesn't sound like Dennis at all :-P

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 40 bytes

```
f x=[v:w|d<-['!'..],v:w<-[filter(==d)x]]
```

Usage example: `f "Ah, abracadabra!"`-> `["!",",","A","aaaaa","bb","c","d","h","rr"]`.

The pattern `v:w` matches only list with at least one element, so all characters not in the input are ignored.

Also 40 bytes:

```
import Data.List
group.sort.filter(>' ')
```

Comment: @ThreeFx: But `group` is from `Data.List`, too. Anyway, I think this syntax is `ghci` only and needs the REPL, so it's a [language of it's own](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7844/34531). I want to stick with standard Haskell.

Answer (score 4):

## C# <s>125</s> 98 Bytes

```
using System.Linq;s=>s.GroupBy(c=>c).Where(g=>g.Key!=' ').Select(g=>new string(g.Key,g.Count())));
```

### Explanation

```
//Using anonymous function to remove the need for a full signature 
//And also allow the implicit return of an IEnumerable
s =>
    
    //Create the groupings
    s.GroupBy(c => c)

    //Remove spaces
    .Where(g=> g.Key!=' ')

    //Generate a new string using the grouping key (the character) and repeating it the correct number of times
    .Select(g => new string(g.Key, g.Count()));
```

- Thanks to @TheLethalCoder who suggested the use of an anonymous function, which also allowed me to remove the `ToArray` call and just implicitly return an IEnumerable which collectively saves 27 bytes

Comment: You can save 18 bytes (if I counted correctly) by compiling it to a `Func<string, string[]>` i.e. `s=>s.GroupBy....`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder are you sure that is acceptable in place of a function, I've always been wary of that because it adds quite a bit of extra boilerplate to be able to execute it, and with the argument for requiring the Linq using it just seems... well wrong.

Comment: Heres a recent example where I do it... http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91075/38550 it'll remove all your boilerplate, as long as functions are allowed

Comment: @TheLethalCoder OK thats good enough for me. :) It also allowed me to remove the ToArray call

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>198</s> <s>189</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```
for(i in unique(a<-strsplit(gsub(" ","",readline()),"")[[1]]))cat(rep(i,sum(a==i)),"\n",sep="")
```

**Ungolfed :**

```
a<-strsplit(gsub(" ","",readline()),"")[[1]] #Takes the input from the console

for(i in unique(a)) #loop over unique characters found in variable a

cat(rep(i,sum(a==i)),"\n",sep="") # print that character n times, where n was the number of times it appeared
```

<s>This solution is currently not entirely working, when `\` are involved.</s>
*Now it is !*

Thank **a lot** you to @JDL for golfing out *102* bytes !

Comment: @JDL : Please suggest edits in the comments. Your changes are really interesting, but it's kinda rude to change someone else's code like that.

Comment: apologies for that, but I didn't have 50 reputation at the time and couldn't make comments. Will do in future though!

Comment: @JDL : Fair enough !

Comment: Try assigning the variable inside a function: `for(i in unique(a=strsplit(gsub(" ","",readline()),"")[[1]]))cat(rep(i,sum(a==i)),"\n",sep="")` — saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @AndreïKostyrka : It doesn't save bytes in this form because you have to put the whole a=strsplit(...) part between brackets: basically does a -2+2 difference. However, using  `<-` will save 1 byte !

Comment: Yep, that was my fault; the old `a` variable was saved in the workspace, causing tha faulty code to work normally.

Comment: It works out slightly better to use `%in%` rather than `gsub` and `rep`. You should check out [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91944/56989) ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 41 + 1 = 42 bytes

+1 byte for `-n` flag.

```ruby
gsub(/(\S)(?!.*\1)/){puts$1*$_.count($1)}
```

Takes input on stdin, e.g.:

```sh
$ echo 'Ah, abracadabra!' | ruby -ne 'gsub(/(\S)(?!.*\1)/){puts$1*$_.count($1)}'
A
h
,
c
d
bb
rr
aaaaa
!
```

Answer (score 4):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 49 bytes

```
i:0(?v
84}0~/&{!*
v!?: <}/?=&:&:<
>&1+&}aol1-?!;^
```

Very spaciously wasteful in the output, but i assume is still allowed given the lenience of the rules

Explanation:

```
i:0(?v           Collects text from input
84}0~/&{!*       adds 32 (first ascii starting at space) to register and 0 to stack
v!?: <}/?=&:&:<  checks all characters to the current register, if equal:
       o         prints the character and continues looping
>&1+&}aol1-?!;^  when all characters are checked, adds 1 to register, prints a newline,
                 checks the stack length to halt the program if 0, and starts looping again
```

fit some things in pretty tight, even using jumps to get around some functions so i could run the pointer vertically.

Basically this puts each ASCII character on its own newline, and if none of that character exists, the line will be blank

[Try it online](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/ZmDkCSR8jYJqHsvJ9)

Edit: i was wrong there was an error in the code what would cause it to never complete if there was a space in the input

Answer (score 4):

## Swift, <s>105</s> 91 bytes

Thanks to @NobodyNada for 14 bytes :)

Yeah, I'm pretty new to Swift...

```
func f(a:[Character]){for c in Set(a){for d in a{if c==d && c != " "{print(c)}}
print("")}}
```

Characters within a group are separated by a single newline. Groups are separated by two newlines.

Comment: You can save 13 bytes by taking input as a `[Character]` instead of a `String`, since the rules say "The input should be a string or an array of chars."  Also, `print("")` can be replaced with just `print()`.

Comment: @NobodyNada `print` without arguments didn't work for some reason but the `[Character]` suggestion was solid. Thanks!

Comment: [82 bytes](https://swiftfiddle.com/3pki3jhjavba3o2o7ujjvq7h4e). And I know it's been years; that link should be for Swift 2.2, which came out in March 2016.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+, 44 bytes

```
[char[]]$args[0]-ne32|group|%{-join$_.Group}
```

Takes input `$args[0]` as a command-line argument literal string. Casts that as a `char`-array, and uses the `-n`ot `e`qual operator to pull out spaces (ASCII `32`). This works because casting has a higher order precedence, and when an array is used as the left-hand operator with a scalar as the right-hand, it acts like a filter.

We pass that array of characters to `Group-Object`, which does exactly what it says. Note that since we're passing *characters*, not strings, this properly groups with case-sensitivity.

Now, we've got a custom object(s) that has group names, counts, etc. If we just print that we'll have a host of extraneous output. So, we need to pipe those into a loop `|%{...}` and each iteration `-join` the `.Group` together into a single string. Those resultant strings are left on the pipeline, and output is implicit at program completion.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\exploded-view-of-substrings.ps1 'Programming Puzzles and Code Golf'
PP
rr
ooo
gg
aa
mm
i
nn
u
zz
ll
ee
s
dd
C
G
f
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

Built-in functions `Gather` and `Characters` do most of the work here.

```
Gather@Select[Characters@#,#!=" "&]&
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
.gksc
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.gksc&input=%27%22Show+me+how+you+do+that+trick%2C+the+one+that+makes+me+scream%22+she+said%27&debug=0)

Takes input as a Python string (i.e. wrapped in quotes, escaped quotes and slashes as necessary).

Explanation:

```
    c    Split (implied) input on whitespace
   s     Sum together
.gk      Group by value
```

If you guarantee at least one space in the input, there's a 4-byte solution:

```
t.gk
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t.gk&input=%27%22Show+me+how+you+do+that+trick%2C+the+one+that+makes+me+scream%22+she+said%27&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
 .gk (Q)  groups the characters in the string by their value
           this sorts them by their value, which guarantees that spaces are first
t         Remove the first element (the spaces)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 11 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Function returning list of strings.

```apl
(⊂∩¨∪)~∘' '
```

`(⊂∩¨∪)` the intersection of the entirety and its unique characters

`~∘' '` except spaces

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%28%u2282%u2229%A8%u222A%29%7E%u2218%27%20%27%29%A8%27Ah%2C%20abracadabra%21%27%20%27%5Co/%5Co/%5Co/%27%20%27A%20man%2C%20a%20plan%2C%20a%20canal%3A%20Panama%21%27%20%27%22Show%20me%20how%20you%20do%20that%20trick%2C%20the%20one%20that%20makes%20me%20scream%22%20she%20said%27&run)

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ðoÑ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT0lQzMlQjBvJUMzJTkxJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9QWglMkMlMjBhYnJhY2FkYWJyYSEmZmxhZ3M9)

`ðo` removes spaces from the string. `Ñ` is a built-in for "group by". There is no body so it just groups identical characters together.

Comment: I don't think spaces are allowed to be one of the groups (by requirement #2).

Comment: @chunes thanks for the heads-up. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 59 bytes

Here's some JS solutions without regex. Uses linebreak as separators between groups.

```javascript
s=>[...s].sort().map(c=>b==(b=c)?c:`
`+c,b=0).join``.trim()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY9Bb8IwDIXv/RVeT4koYWemgDhwR9qRIsV1U1po4irJNvHru1QVB@uznp/19B74i5HCMKWt59bOnZ6jPlyVUvGmIockpHI4CdKHRmvRaJJH2pvCbKhq9KdUDx68MSqFwQk5f10LAHPqK8AmIGG74MNUi1rXvHvPqpzAoc9WmMaVhB7HPVwy3Put/O75D5yFBS/@gZYh9ZggR9KzyrsF9nbVHD5tXMy5k0VXQszXiENripvqOJyRepELEvvIo1Uj30UnotyUtS@lnP8B)

---

Alternative that might not be supported by some browsers because of `at(-1)` (**62 bytes**) :

```javascript
s=>[...s].sort().map(c=>a+=a.at(-1)==c?c:`
`+c,a="")&&a.trim()
```

Try it:

```js
f=s=>[...s].sort().map(c=>a+=a.at(-1)==c?c:`
`+c,a="")&&a.trim()

;[
  `Ah, abracadabra!`,
  `\\o/\\o/\\o/`,
  `A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!`,
  `"Show me how you do that trick, the one that makes me scream" she said`
].forEach(s=>console.log(f(s)))
```

---

Alternative funny solution (**67 bytes**) :

```javascript
s=>[...s].sort().map(a=c=>c!=' '?a[c]=[a[c]]+c:0)&&Object.values(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY@xbsMwDET3fAWTIZFQV@2cQikydG6Bjo4BM7RcO5FEQ1JS9OtdCUYG8hHHu@EueMdIYZzSs@fOzL2eoz7USqnYqMghCakcTgI16QOt9Q5271hTo@uymyfav8rt9vN8MZTUHe3NRIFyfqtXAO1xqADPAQm7gnVbFfV04pfHLMoRHPpshckuJPRo9/CV4R6xzffAv@AMFPzxDTqGNGCCFEa6Vvk2wN4smsOricWcuxl0G4j5G3Hs2lWjeg4fSIPIRYl9ZGuU5R/RiyilnP8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <del>53</del> <del>50</del> 46 bytes

```
l'~')?v0
v?(0:i<]r+1r[
\~rvol-1
^?:<;?('!'l~oa
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#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)

Finally beat the current fish answer. Note the link pre-populates the stack to make it faster but this is unnecessary for the correctness of the program.

Each element of the stack stores how often the nth character appears in the input.

[image]

The top row pushes `ord('~')` 0s to the stack.

The second row reads the input. Use `[r1+r]` to get the nth element of the stack, add 1 to it, then put it back into place.

The left (red) half of the third row reverses the stack so the higher valued items are on the top. Now we know that the length of the stack is the character code of the count the top element represents. This allows very convenient printing.

The left (grey) half of the bottom row checks if the count of the nth character is 0. If so go to the right half of the third row.

The right (blue) half of the bottom row prints a line break `ao`. Then pops the top of the stack. If we now have less than `ord('!')` items on the stack only spaces remain and we exit (since we shouldn't print spaces)

The right half of the third row runs if there is more than one occurrence of the top character. If so, we subtract one occurrence, then print the length of the stack as a character.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

-1 byte from @doug's improvement

```
{.x" "_=x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJylkstugzAQRff+ionVRSpBXKmbBtRF/iBSlknUOMYEBMYUO4UoSr+99jhpHpsuegEdgx+6d4Y8OU4GCvTjfTgRYpPj0/Lw3SU5AAzpRlfpeJPzsk6H9JB2z+sTsUs6KyLg244LnnmMKIFxRGcOENEiIPKg3AtH2y2i68K0CMgCRvR57Q9erTS7PP5Q98ELd2qtkYwxvxrQCCjeOC/Q1oGCN7xOYO6g7nxRpa6Gfk01TjiIomCkxbe6vjOZBMxvvKJZuih0D0qCx0HvIdNgC27BdqWoIjeWoBsZvileSeMXG9FJrlYUjJs2vMxCUHeF8xdooUBdgp+j9/05yjmMDAr7DgF7nMmwsNSiHjoRWkDLEiEwJK2qm7ZFNFTFOGFaRgprW5MwJnQmd7rOJ8ZyUclBFLzZyYnQin3upbGlbgybvkzfXpkc2tqtzuKvUvaxzmMeG1eZZkfI4w9EfM/xJn+0lPyn6NeaE/IDwivNJg==)

Returns characters in order of appearance in original input.

- `=x` group the input, returning a dictionary mapping distinct values to the indices in which they appear in the input
- `" "_` remove the space character
- `.x` index back into the input using the indices returned above, and return just the values of the dictionary (i.e. the list of repeated characters)

Comment: Couldn't this be `{.x" "_=x}`?

Comment: Yep! A nice simplification, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ñ x ó¥
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=8SB4IPOl&input=IkFoLCBhYnJhY2FkYWJyYSEi)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 65 bytes

```r
cat(strrep(z<-names(y<-table(strsplit(readline(),""))),y)[z>" "])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMFNk6LUxJSczLxU27TSvOSSzPw8DU0lR4XcxDwdhUSFghwInZyYl5hjpRAApHITFZWWlpak6VrcdExOLNEoLikqSi3QqLLRBcqlFmtU2uiWJCblpIIkigtyMks0YDZoaOooKWlqaupUakZX2SkpKMVqQgxaAKWgNAA)

Full program that accepts input by reading a line from the terminal, and outputs a space-separated string of character-groups.  The input & output are chosen to be directly comparable to the earlier R answers of [Billywob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91944/95126) and [Frédéric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91000/95126).

Nevertheless, we could also golf a little further within the original rules, by writing a function that accepts input as an array of characters, and outputs an array of strings:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 49 bytes

```r
function(x)strrep(z<-names(y<-table(x)),y)[z>" "]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3DdNK85JLMvPzNCo0i0uKilILNKpsdPMSc1OLNSptdEsSk3JSgVKaOpWa0VV2SgpKsVCNTpl5BaUltkA9xQU5mSUaSo4KuYl5OgqJCgU5EDo5MS8xx0ohAEjlJioq6SgpaUZHG8bGcqVpgPVqQkxasABCAwA)

Note that this could be further shortened to [42 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3tWI0KjSLS4qKUgs0qmx08xJzU4s1Km10SxKTclKBUpo6lZrRVXZKCkqxUB1OmXkFpSW2QD3FBTmZJRpKjgq5iXk6CokKBTkQOjkxLzHHSiEASOUmKirpKClpRkcbxsZypWmA9WpCTFqwAEIDAA) using a version of R that is more-recent than the challenge to allow us to exchange `function` for `\`.

Answer (score 2):

## Processing, 109 bytes

```
void s(char[] x){x=sort(x);char l=0;for(char c:x){if(c!=l)println();if(c!=' '&&c!='\n'&&c!='\t')print(c);l=c;}}
```

Its the brute force approach, sort the array, then loop through it.  If it doesn't match the last character printed, print a newline first.  If it is whitespace, skip the printing step.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 61 bytes

```
@(x)mat2cell(y=strtrim(sort(x)),1,diff(find([1 diff(+y) 1])))
```

This is an anoymous function that takes a string as input and outputs a cell arrray of strings.

[Try at Ideone](http://ideone.com/WoRneV).

#### How it works

- `sort` sorts the input string. In particular, spaces will be at the beginning.
- `strtrim` removes leading spaces.
- `diff(+y)` computes consecutive differences between characters (to detect group boundaries)...
- ... so `diff(find([1 diff(+y) 1])` gives a vector of group sizes.
- `mat2cell` then splits the sorted string into chunks with those sizes.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (using external Library - Enumerable) (<s>78</s> 67 bytes)

```
 n=>_.From(n).Where(y=>y!=' ').GroupBy(x=>x).WriteLine(y=>y.Write())
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

Code explanation: This is what Enumerable was made to do! Load the string into the library, which converts it to a char array. Filter out the white space entries. Group by char. Write each group to a line, according to the specified predicate. That predicate says to join all the elements of the current group into a string, without a delimiter.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Perl6, <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 45

```
slurp.comb.Bag.kv.map:{$^a.trim&&say $a x$^b}
```

Thanks to manatwork for the improvements.

Comment: Not a big improvement, but `$a.trim` seems to do it for the condition.

Comment: Seems the logical operators still not need spaces around them, so  `$^a.trim&&say $a x$^b` works. (Sorry for adding the hints byte by byte, but this is my first try on Perl6.)

Comment: Little typo, you accidentally removed the opening `{`.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash + coreutils, <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 45 bytes

```sh
sed 's: ::g;s:\(.\)\1*:& :g'<<<`fold -1|sort`
```

There is no separator between the characters of a group and the groups are separated by space. There is one trailing group separator, but as I understood that's acceptable.

**Run:**

```sh
./explode_view.sh <<< '\o /\ o /\ o k'
```

**Output:**

```sh
// \\\ k ooo
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 7 bytes

```
Xz!t7XQ
```

[**MATL Online Demo**](https://matl.io/?code=Xz%21t7XQ&inputs=%27Ah%2C+abracadabra%21%27&version=19.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 35 bytes

```
->s{(?!..?~).map{|x|s.scan x}-[[]]}
```

Tried to turn the problem upside down to save some bytes.
Instead of starting with the string, start with the possible character set.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸¬ü
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=uKz8&input=IkEgbWFuLCBhIHBsYW4sIGEgY2FuYWw6IFBhbmFtYSEi)

```
¸¬ü     :Implicit input of string
¸       :Split on spaces
 ¬      :Join
  ü     :Group & sort
        :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 35 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IoUJBQ6Vao7TYykrTUF9foVbTxsZGpRrIjI5TqYit/f//v2OGjkJiUlFicmIKiFIEAA)

```sh
for x (${(us::)1// })<<<${1//[^$x]}
```

Input via argument `$1`. Expression `${(us::)1// }` splits `$1` to array of unique chars, and removes spaces. Iterate over the unique array. For each `x`, print `$1`, removing non-`x` chars.

<s>[45 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/f0VZDpVqj2MpK07BW0zotv0ihQgEkUqrpWKtpY2MDZPpmAWUdlVUqav8D1WfoKCQmFSUmJ6aAKEUA)</s>: `A=(${(s::)1});for x (${(u)A})<<<${(Mj::)A#$x}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 26 bytes

```arturo
$=>[sort&--` `|chunk=>[&]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?KjLKeY)

Takes input as a list of characters.

```
$=>[           ; a function where input is assigned to &
    sort       ; sort
    &--` `     ; input with spaces removed
    |          ; then
    chunk=>[&] ; split into groups of equal contiguous characters
]              ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Cr3J)

```
->s{(s.chars-[' ']).uniq.map{|c|c*s.count(c)}}
```

My original full program version, 48 bytes after adding the `n` flag:

```
p gsub(/\s/){}.chars.uniq.map{|c|c*$_.count(c)}
```

Comment: Can you replace `.count(c)` with `.count c` ?

Comment: @Cyoce no, because the `*` operator is present nearby so the parser will complain.

Comment: s.chars-[' ']|[] inside the brackets would avoid the uniq

Comment: @GB It would, but if we're chaining it to `map` then it needs extra parens, and `((s.chars-[' '])|[]).map` has the same number of characters as `(s.chars-[' ']).uniq.map`. And the other, shorter way to check unique characters (via regex) is already covered by @Jordan in another answer

Comment: It works **inside** the brackets, you don't need extra brackets because precedence of '-' is higher.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 107

Could be shortened by lambda, but later

```
x=sorted(input())
i=0
while i<len(x):x[i:]=['  '*(x[i]!=x[i-1])]+x[i:];i-=~(x[i]!=x[i-1])
print("".join(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 10 bytes

```
{S-$e`::*}
```

An unnamed block that expects the string on top of the stack and replaces it with a list of strings.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=IlwiU2hvdyBtZSBob3cgeW91IGRvIHRoYXQgdHJpY2ssIHRoZSBvbmUgdGhhdCBtYWtlcyBtZSBzY3JlYW1cIiBzaGUgc2FpZCIKCntTLSRlYDo6Kn0KCn5w&input=)

#### Explanation

```
S-  Remove spaces.
$   Sort.
e`  Run-length encode, gives pairs [R C], where R is the run-length and
    C is the character.
::* Repeat the C in each pair R times.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, <s>16</s> 9 bytes

```
d-}F/i*d+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=d-%7DF%2Fi%2ad%2B&input=Ah%2C+abracadabra%21%21&warnings=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 123

```
(lambda(s &aux(w(string-trim" "(sort s'char<))))(princ(elt w 0))(reduce(lambda(x y)(unless(char= x y)(terpri))(princ y))w))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(lambda (s &aux (w (string-trim " " (sort s 'char<))))
  (princ (elt w 0))
  (reduce
    (lambda (x y) 
      (unless (char= x y) (terpri))
      (princ y))
  w))
```

Not the most golf friendly language. This could probably be modified to return list of lists instead of printing string.

Answer (score 1):

## Emacs, 36 keystrokes

<kbd>C-SPACE</kbd> <kbd>C-E</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`sort-r`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd><kbd>C-A</kbd><kbd>C-M-S-%</kbd>`\(\(.\)\2*\)`<kbd>RETURN</kbd>`\1`<kbd>C-Q</kbd><kbd>C-J</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>

#### Result

`A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!` -->

```
!
,,
:
A
P
aaaaaaaaa
c
ll
mm
nnnn
p
```

#### Explanation

1. <kbd>C-SPACE</kbd> <kbd>C-E</kbd>
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sort-r`<kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>RETURN</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>
3. <kbd>C-A</kbd>
4. <kbd>C-M-S-%</kbd> `\(\(.\)\2*\)`<kbd>RETURN</kbd>`\1` <kbd>C-Q</kbd> <kbd>C-J</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>

1. Select the input line;
2. Call `sort-regexp-fields` with arguments `.` and `.`;

   - Argument #1: *Regexp scpecifying records to sort*
   - Argument #2: *Regexp scpecifying key within records*
3. Return at line start;
4. Apply regexp substitution `\(\(.\)\2*\)` -> `\1\n` on all matches.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 67 bytes

Space as separator

PHP5 using deprecated `ereg_replace` function.

```
for(;++$i<128;)echo ereg_replace("[^".chr($i)."]","",$argv[1])." ";
```

PHP7, 73 bytes

```
for(;++$i<128;)echo str_repeat($j=chr($i),substr_count($argv[1],$j))." ";
```

Using built in is worse :(

```
foreach(array_count_values(str_split($argv[1]))as$a=>$b)echo str_repeat($a,$b)." ";
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 31 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with input on STDIN:

```
explode.pl <<< "ab.ceaba.d"
```

`explode.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%.%$&x s/\Q$&//g.$/%eg;y/
//s
```

If you don't care about spurious newlines inbetween the lines the following 24 bytes version works too:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%.%$&x s/\Q$&//g.$/%eg
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 123 bytes

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(c)WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 1)FROM(SELECT SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL,1)c FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(:1))GROUP BY c;
```

Un-golfed

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(c)WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 1)
FROM (SELECT SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL,1)c FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(:1))
GROUP BY c
```

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://esolangs.org/wiki/S.I.L.O.S) 265

The (non competing) code better input format is at the bottom, feel free to [try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=CmRlZiA6IGxibApsb2FkTGluZSA6CmEgPSAyNTYKOmEKOnMKeCA9IGdldCBhCnogPSB4CnogLSAzMgp6IHwKaWYgeiB1CmEgKyAxCkdPVE8gcwo6dQppZiB4IGMKR09UTyBlCjpjCmIgPSB4CmIgKyA1MTIKYyA9IGdldCBiCmMgKyAxCnNldCBiIGMKYSArIDEKaWYgeCBhCjplCmEgPSA1MTIKYiA9IDc2OApsID0gMTAKOloKaiA9IGEKaiAtIGIKaWYgaiB6CnogPSBnZXQgYQpjID0gYQpjIC0gNTEyCjozCmlmIHogQwpwcmludENoYXIgbAphICsgMQpHT1RPIFoKOkMKcHJpbnRDaGFyIGMKeiAtIDEKR09UTyAzCjp6&input=&args=VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0IGlucHV0IHdpdGhvdXQgYW55IG5ld2xpbmVzLiBBQUFBQUEgQkJCQkIgVGhlIHF1aWNrIEJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wZWQgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2cgMTIzNDU2Nzg5MCE)

```
def : lbl
loadLine :
a = 256
:a
:s
x = get a
z = x
z - 32
z |
if z u
a + 1
GOTO s
:u
if x c
GOTO e
:c
b = x
b + 512
c = get b
c + 1
set b c
a + 1
if x a
:e
a = 512
b = 768
l = 10
:Z
j = a
j - b
if j z
z = get a
c = a
c - 512
:3
if z C
printChar l
a + 1
GOTO Z
:C
printChar c
z - 1
GOTO 3
:z
```

Input for the above is a series of command line arguments representing ascii values, terminated with a zero.[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=CmRlZiA6IGxibAo6YQo6cwpyZWFkSU8gOgp4ID0gaQp6ID0geAp6IC0gMzIKeiB8CmlmIHogdQpHT1RPIHMKOnUKaWYgeCBjCkdPVE8gZQo6YwpiID0geApiICsgNTEyCmMgPSBnZXQgYgpjICsgMQpzZXQgYiBjCmlmIHggYQo6ZQphID0gNTEyCmIgPSA3NjgKbCA9IDEwCjpaCmogPSBhCmogLSBiCmlmIGogegp6ID0gZ2V0IGEKYyA9IGEKYyAtIDUxMgo6MwppZiB6IEMKcHJpbnRDaGFyIGwKYSArIDEKR09UTyBaCjpDCnByaW50Q2hhciBjCnogLSAxCkdPVE8gMwo6eg&input=NjQ&args=NjU+MTIz+NjU+NjU+NjU+NjY+NjY+MA).

---

For a more reasonable method of input we must up the byte count (and use features that were nonexistent before the writing of this challenge).

For 291 bytes we get the following code.

```
\
def : lbl
loadLine :
a = 256
:a
:s
x = get a
z = x
z - 32
z |
if z u
a + 1
GOTO s
:u
if x c
GOTO e
:c
b = x
b + 512
c = get b
c + 1
set b c
a + 1
if x a
:e
a = 512
b = 768
l = 10
:Z
j = a
j - b
if j z
z = get a
c = a
c - 512
:3
if z C
printChar l
a + 1
GOTO Z
:C
printChar c
z - 1
GOTO 3
:z
```

Feel free to [test this version online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=CmRlZiA6IGxibApsb2FkTGluZSA6CmEgPSAyNTYKOmEKOnMKeCA9IGdldCBhCnogPSB4CnogLSAzMgp6IHwKaWYgeiB1CmEgKyAxCkdPVE8gcwo6dQppZiB4IGMKR09UTyBlCjpjCmIgPSB4CmIgKyA1MTIKYyA9IGdldCBiCmMgKyAxCnNldCBiIGMKYSArIDEKaWYgeCBhCjplCmEgPSA1MTIKYiA9IDc2OApsID0gMTAKOloKaiA9IGEKaiAtIGIKaWYgaiB6CnogPSBnZXQgYQpjID0gYQpjIC0gNTEyCjozCmlmIHogQwpwcmludENoYXIgbAphICsgMQpHT1RPIFoKOkMKcHJpbnRDaGFyIGMKeiAtIDEKR09UTyAzCjp6&input=&args=VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0IGlucHV0IHdpdGhvdXQgYW55IG5ld2xpbmVzLiBBQUFBQUEgQkJCQkIgVGhlIHF1aWNrIEJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wZWQgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2cgMTIzNDU2Nzg5MCE). The backslash is unnecessary but is there to show the important leading line feed.

Answer (score 1):

### ARM machine code on Linux, 60 bytes

Hex Dump:

```
b590 4c0d f810 2b01 b11a 58a3 3301 50a3 e7f8 6222 2704 2001 f1ad 0101 2201 237f 5ce5 b135 700b df00 3d01 d8fc 250a 700d df00 3b01 d8f4 bd90 000200bc
```

This function basically creates an array of size 128, and whenever it reads a character from the input string it increment's the value at that characters position. Then it goes back through the array and prints each character array[character] times.

Ungolfed Assembly (GNU syntax):

```
.syntax unified
.bss @bss is zero-initialized data (doesn't impact code size)
countArray:
    .skip 128 @countArray[x] is the number of occurances of x

.text
.global expStr
.thumb_func
expstr:
    @Input: r0 - a NUL-terminated string.
    @Output: Groups of characters to STDOUT
    push {r4,r7,lr}
    ldr r4,=countArray @Load countArray into r4
    readLoop:
        ldrb r2,[r0],#1 @r2=*r0++
        cbz r2,endReadLoop @If r2==NUL, break
        ldr r3,[r4,r2] @r3=r4[r2]
        adds r3,r3,#1 @r3+=1
        str r3,[r4,r2] @r4[r2]=r3
        b readLoop @while (true)
    endReadLoop:
    @Now countArray[x] is the number of occurances of x.
    @Also, r2 is zero
    str r2,[r4,#' ] @'<character> means the value of <character>
    @What that just did was set the number of spaces found to zero.
    movs r7,#4 @4 is the system call for write
    movs r0,#1 @1 is stdout
    sub r1,sp,#1 @Allocate 1 byte on the stack
    @Also r1 is the char* used for write
    movs r2,#1 @We will print 1 character at a time
    movs r3,#127 @Loop through all the characters
    writeLoop:
        ldrb r5,[r4,r3] @r5=countArray[r3]
        cbz r5,endCharacterLoop @If we're not printing anything, go past the loop
        strb r3,[r1] @We're going to print byte r3, so we store it at *r0
        characterLoop:
            swi #0 @Make system call
            @Return value of write is number of characters printed in r0
            @Since we're printing one character, it should just return 1, which
            @means r0 didn't change.
            subs r5,r5,#1
            bhi characterLoop
        @If we're here then we're done printing our group of characters
        @Thus we just need to print a newline.
        movs r5,#10 @r5='\n' (reusing r5 since we're done using it as a loop counter
        strb r5,[r1]
        swi #0 @Print the character

        endCharacterLoop:
        subs r3,r3,#1
        bhi writeLoop @while (--r3)
    pop {r4,r7,pc}
.ltorg @Store constants here
```

Testing script (also assembly):

```
.global _start
_start:
    ldr r0,[sp,#8] @Read argv[1]
    bl expstr @Call function
    movs r7,#1 @1 is the system call for exit
    swi #0 @Make system call
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 53 bytes

```
def?(s:String)=s.filter(_!=' ').groupBy(identity).map{_._2.mkString}
```

When run with REPL:

```
scala> ?("Ah, abracadabra!")
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(!, A, aaaaa, ,, bb, c, h, rr, d)

scala> print(res2.mkString("\n"))
!
A
aaaaa
,
bb
c
h
rr
d
```

EDIT:
Forgot to filter spaces

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 46

```
#(partition-by identity(sort(re-seq #"\S" %)))
```

Long and descriptive function names for simplest of things, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 65

@TimmyD has the shorter answer but I don't have enough rep to comment. Here's my answer in 65 bytes.

I didn't think to use `group` and I didn't know that you could stick `-join` in front of something instead of `-join""` on the end and save two characters (using that would make my method 63).

```
([char[]]$args[0]-ne32|sort|%{if($l-ne$_){"`n"};$_;$l=$_})-join""
```

My method sorts the array, then loops through it and concatenates characters if they match the preceding entry, inserting a newline if they do not.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure (55 bytes)

```
(defn f[s](map(fn[[a b]](repeat b a))(frequencies s)))
```

Test Cases:

```
(f "Ah, abracadabra!")
;;=> ((\space) (\!) (\A) (\a \a \a \a \a) (\b \b) (\c) (\d) (\h) (\,) (\r \r))

(f "\\o/\\o/\\o/")
;;=> ((\\ \\ \\) (\o \o \o) (\/ \/ \/))

(f "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!")
;;=> ((\space \space \space \space \space \space) (\!) (\A) (\a \a \a \a \a \a \a \a \a) (\c) (\, \,) (\l \l) (\m \m) (\n \n \n \n) (\P) (\p) (\:))

(f "\"Show me how you do that trick, the one that makes me scream\" she said")
;;=> ((\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space) (\a \a \a \a \a) (\" \") (\c \c) (\d \d) (\e \e \e \e \e \e \e) (\h \h \h \h \h \h) (\i \i) (\k \k) (\,) (\m \m \m \m) (\n) (\o \o \o \o \o) (\r \r) (\S) (\s \s \s \s) (\t \t \t \t \t \t) (\u) (\w \w) (\y))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>121</s> <s>120</s> <s>110</s> 103 Bytes

```
s->s.chars().distinct().filter(c->c!=32)
    .forEach(c->out.println(s.replaceAll("[^\\Q"+(char)c+"\\E]","")))
```

Above lambda can be consumed with Java-8 `Consumer`. It fetches distinct characters and replaces other characters of the String to disassemble each character occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org), 70 bytes

```
def f(s), do: '#{s}'|>Enum.group_by(&(&1))|>Map.delete(32)|>Map.values
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 67 bytes

Even though there's already an R-answer by @Frédéric I thought my solution deserves it's own answer because it's conceptually different.

```
for(i in unique(x<-strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]]))cat(x[x%in%i]," ")
```

The program prints the ascii characters in order of appearence in the string where groups are separated by two white spaces and chars within groups by one white space. A special case is if the string has whitespaces in itself, then at one specific place in the output there will be `4+number of white spaces in string` white spaces separating two groups E.g:

`Ah, abracadabra!` => `A  h  ,     a a a a a  b b  r r  c  d  !`

#### Ungolfed

Split up the code for clarity even though assignment is done within the unique functions and changed to order of evaluation:

```
x<-strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]]) # Read string from command line and convert into vector

for(i in unique(x){              # For each unique character of the string, create vector 
  cat(x[x%in%i]," ")             # of TRUE/FALSE and return the elements in x for which 
}                                # these are matched
```

Answer (score 1):

**C, 178**

```
#define F for
#define i8 char
#define R return
z(i8*r,i8*e,i8*a){i8*b,c;F(;*a;++a)if(!isspace(c=*a)){F(b=a;*b;++b)if(r>=e)R-1;else if(*b==c)*b=' ',*r++=c;*r++='\n';}*r=0;R 0;}
```

z(outputArray,LastPointerOkinOutputarray,inputArray) return -1 on error 0 ok
Note:Modify its input array too...

```
#define P printf
main(){char a[]="A, 12aa99dd333aA,,<<", b[256]; z(b,b+255,a);P("r=%s\n", b);}

/*
 178
 r=AA
 ,,,
 1
 2
 aaa
 99
 dd
 333
 <<
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 243 bytes

```
(let*((l(sort(string->list s)char<?))(g(λ(k i)(list-ref k i))))(let loop((i 1)(ol(list(g l 0))))(cond((= i(length l))
(reverse ol))((equal?(g l(- i 1))(g l i))(loop(+ 1 i)(cons(g l i)ol)))(else(loop(+ 1 i)(cons(g l i)(cons #\newline ol)))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s)
  (let*((l (sort (string->list s) char<?))
        (g (λ (k i)(list-ref k i))) )
    (let loop ((i 1)
               (ol (list (g l 0))))
      (cond
        ((= i (length l)) (reverse ol))
        ((equal? (g l (- i 1)) (g l i))
         (loop (+ 1 i) (cons (g l i) ol)))
        (else (loop (+ 1 i) (cons (g l i) (cons #\newline ol))))
        ))))
```

Testing:

```
(display (f "Ah, abracadabra!"))
```

Output:

```
(  
 ! 
 , 
 A 
 a a a a a 
 b b 
 c 
 d 
 h 
 r r)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 1.5 bytes (3 nibbles)

```
=~|
```

```
=~|     # full program
=~|$$$  # with implicit args added;
  |     # filter
   $    # the input
    $   # by itself (=remove spaces),
=~      # now group the remaining characters by
     $  # themselves
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 37 bytes

```
[ " " without [ ] collect-by values ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JcwxCsJAEIXhPqd4BuxML7GyEhFEEKuQYhw2JDjZjdlZxbPYpNELeJrcxoVliq-Yn_f-NsTqxmk-XM77464Eee_Ywxv16Fz0Hoxl43EzozWCTZblW_RkVyAMkmSyJCVOkZ4W-SdoU6znZYU83rPT1gVFhRrsRAxrcX3hQRLibJ3iH5NITIaxsxpDQ9ymzzQl_w)

- `" " without` remove spaces
- `[ ] collect-by` group letters by letter
- `values` discard the keys

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ðK{γ
```

Outputs as a list.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Abv6nOb//93zNBRSEwqSkxOTAFRigA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NYsxCgIxEEWv8p06YG@zbG0jWBqL2SSQsJuNJKsS7D2AJxE8gr2H8CIxy2IxvPl/3oTEnTPlkhvC9/4ANbm8n9vb51VEOVBrBbiLrFjPWJEgKcP6PzW28DxWCadhoeKRhw12FX55oL0NV3iDGTmcoQMmyxOm6FQv6m4QRrN0nnuTZjmpaNhLQqrnxE7T8Qc).

`ðK` could alternatively be `ðм` or `#J` for the same byte-count.

**Explanation:**

```python
ðK    # Remove all spaces from the (implicit) input-string
  {   # Sort the remaining characters
   γ  # Group adjacent equal characters together in substrings
      # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)

ðм    # (Vectorized) remove all spaces from the (implicit) input-string

#     # Split the (implicit) input-string by spaces (no-op if the input doesn't contain
      # any spaces)
 J    # Join this list back together to a string (or no-op, by joining the stack
      # consisting of just the single string if the input didn't contained any spaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) +coreutils, 55 bytes

```bash
for x in `fold -1|tee a|sort|uniq`;{ grep $x a|rs -g0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SKFCITNPISEtPydFQdewpiQ1VSGxpji/qKSmNC@zMMG6WiG9KLVAQaUCKFxUrKCbbmBd@/@/Y4aOQmJSUWJyYgqIUvwPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES5): <strike>50</strike> 48 bytes

As a function:

```
function(i){return i.split("").sort().join(" ")}
```

The important code, replace the empty string with the search string (29 bytes):

```
"".split("").sort().join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell - 86

I imagine I could get this smaller, but I'll work on it later. This assumes that `$d` contains the string to explode.

```
$s="";$i=0;[Array]::Sort(($a=$d-split""));$a|%{$s+=$_;if($a[++$i]-cne$_){$s+="`n"}};$s
```

Comment: [Assuming the input is in a pre-defined variable is not an allowed input method.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8731/42963)